# cURL on Linux not compiled, although installed,why?

Tags: php, linux, curl

the `phpinfo()` shows 
[image]

but when i install `zencart` on my `vps` hosting. it shows 
[image]

[image]

why? how to correct it?

Comment: Are you sure both are using the same PHP?

Comment: yeah,i am sure, the php -v shows the same version with the phpinfo shows

Comment: Do you have actual access to libcurl on your server?  E.g. can you run `curl` from the command line?

Comment: Which code does zencart use to probe for curl before showing that message? Is that phpinfo run from the same VPS as zencart is?

Comment: tandu， i don't know how torun curl from the command line. could you tell me how to execute it? thank you

Comment: mario, they are on the same VPS.same directory.  i installed the zencart 1.39 version. when goes to  check the environment step, it shows the curl not compied into php.

Comment: Run the following: `ldd $(which php) | grep -i curl` and `curl --version` and share the output of the commands with us. Also, does the "Configure command" from phpinfo's output includes "--with-curl"?

Comment: ciupinet， thank you. i have updated my question. and putted the screeshot.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are missing SSL support from your PHP and that's what ZenCart actually tries to do: request a HTTPS URL. Not sure but if it runs against localhost then you also need to make sure you have something listening on port 443.